# silverstripe - content permissions have no effect

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

in silverstripe/security in the Permissions for Content Authors there is a section called 'Content permissions' with these Checkboxes:

- View any page
- Edit any page
- Change site structure
- View draft content

if I disable all Checkboxes then just 'Change site structure' has an effect. the content author can still view and edit, although it was disabled...

is this a bug or a feature?

many thx,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

The "View" and "Edit" Group permissions from memory allow that Group to view or edit pages EVEN if in the SiteTree an individual page level access has been set so that a specific group isn't supposed to edit it.

Guess it acts like an override. Unsure of the design reasons why.

If you hover over the permissions, some of them give descriptions.